# @JsonSerializable, how to print embedded objects in Json as well, in flutter/dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am trying to convert the entire object into Json. For example if I have two classes

```
@JsonSerializable
class A{
String name;
int age;
List<B> list;
A({this.name, this.age, this.list})

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AToJson(this);
factory A.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$AFromJson(json);

}

@JsonSerializable
Class B{
String friendsName;
int age;
B({this.friendsName, this.age})

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$BToJson(this);
factory B.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$BFromJson(json);

}
```

When I try to execute:

```
print(a.toJson());// a being object of A
```

I get 'name' and 'age' fine **but** 'list' comes as [instance of 'B']

I am trying to print everything in Json, how do I go about it in this given structure? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Override the `toString` method of the `B` class:

```dart
@JsonSerializable
class B {
  String friendsName;
  int age;

  B({this.friendsName, this.age})

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$BToJson(this);

  factory B.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$BFromJson(json);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '($friendsName, $age)';
  }
}
```